# How do I move an element on a canvas around with an animation?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, move

I have been looking for a while on how to move a certain square around on a canvas with JavaScript, and haven't found much. I have done one where it removes itself and replaces itself every frame, but I want it to be smoother and animated. This is my code:

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid grey;"></canvas><br />
<button onclick="#">Move Up</button>
<script>
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(20, 60, 20, 20);
</script>
```

So far the button does nothing, is there a function I could add that would move the square around? (in this case up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make smooth animations, check about the `requestAnimationFrame` function (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame).

Here an example with your code:

```js
canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var squareY = 60;
var isButtonPressed = false;

ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
ctx.fillRect(20, squareY, 20, 20);

function moveUp() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(moveUp);

  if (isButtonPressed) {
    squareY -= 10 / 16;
  }

  squareY = Math.max(squareY, 5);

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
  ctx.fillRect(20, squareY, 20, 20);
}

function onMouseUp() {
  isButtonPressed = false;
}

function onMouseDown() {
  isButtonPressed = true;
}
canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var squareY = 60;
var isButtonPressed = false;

ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
ctx.fillRect(20, squareY, 20, 20);

function moveUp() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(moveUp);

  if (isButtonPressed) {
    squareY -= 10 / 16;
  }

  squareY = Math.max(squareY, 5);

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
  ctx.fillRect(20, squareY, 20, 20);
}

function onMouseUp() {
  isButtonPressed = false;
}

function onMouseDown() {
  isButtonPressed = true;
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.key == 'ArrowUp') {
    // if the arrow key is pressed
    squareY -= 10 / 16;
  }
});

moveUp();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid grey;"></canvas><br />
<button onmousedown="onMouseDown()" onmouseup="onMouseUp()">Move Up</button>
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! this works, now is it possible to have the square move only when your holding the button?

Comment: @maxmeinz I just edited the answer, check it above.

Comment: Ok, ill take a look and see if I understand anything haha

Comment: what does onmouseup="onMouseUp()" do?

Comment: Oh wait i got it, ok, when you hold and release it.

Comment: Also one more thing, is there a way to move it up when you press the up arrow?

Comment: @maxmeinz I've added a `window.addEventListener('keydown')` on the example. The function is called everytime a key is down, I test if the key pressed is the ArrowUp, and if so, move the square up.

Comment: alright, thanks, ill stop bothering you now, lol. what i tried before was similar, it was:
window.onkeypress = function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 38) {
      squareY -= 10 / 16;
   }
}
the indentation is going to be messed up by this comment I think though.

Comment: The square moves faster in high-refresh rate screens, though. Maybe you should check how much the square should move using the first argument.

Comment: Ok, ill look at that.